# What to call a Christmas present in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, contemporary-latin

What would be a good way to call Christmas presents on contemporary Latin?
Are there attested Latin descriptions of early Christmas where presents are given, or should we perhaps choose something newer?
My intuition says *donum natalicium*, but it is certainly not the only possible phrasing.

Merry Christmas everyone!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's totally clear one is talking about Christmas, your choice is fair enough.

Otherwise, I suggest *donum Nativitatis*.

First of all, the only alternative to *donum* would be *munus*, but this has many other meanings, and most importantly even in this context it often has the specific connotation of a favour.

As for *Natalis* or *natalicium*, I prefer the genitive of *Nativitas* because the former usually mean a general "anniversary" if not "birthday", and in fact *donum natalicium* would normally be understood as "birthday gift". The *Carmina Natalicia* by Paulinus of Nola (355–431) were "anniversary poems" in honour of St Felix.

While *Nativitas* is also not totally unambiguous, when capitalized it is more easily recognized as Christmas even without specifying *Domini* or *Christi*.
I've found three amusing websites that talk about *dona Nativitatis* - see [here](http://la.wondershare.com/convert-video-audio/christmas-gift-ideas.html), [here](http://www.theyarniad.com/2009/12/christmas-crafting-part-first-dona.html), [here](http://www.latinlanguage.us/blog/index.php?blog=2&title=donum_nativitatis_1&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1).

Answer (score 1):

*[Strena](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dstrena)*, a new year's gift, may be the word you are looking for. If I wanted to mean a seasonal gift that shows that I am thinking of you, I'd use *strena*.

On the other hand, if I was looking for a word to indicate a gift commemorating the birth of Christ, I'd go with somwething like *donum pro Christinatale* or what not.